# Use of Disapproved vs Unapproved vs Denied

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When submitting a memorandum request for approval of something and providing options of for the signer...  what is the best way to word the denial option ?  Disapproved?  Denied?  Unapproved?

This is intended to allow the approver to circle their response.

- Approved / Denied
- Approved / Disapproved
- Approved / Unapproved

I feel *disapproved* is not the correct word...  since they may disapprove of the request in theory but that doesn't mean they're saying no to the action.  *Denied* seems to be more definitive. *Unapproved* works but seems lackluster in some way and may indicate the action was taken without prior approval or something similar to that.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146152/discussion-on-question-by-bjh-use-of-disapproved-vs-unapproved-vs-denied); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: It depends on the business logic. What happens after the person rejects it? You say *denied* seems definitive, but is the decision definitive?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Approved/Denied.

The logic is: the signer is indicating "yes - approval is given" or "no - approval is not given".

- Approved/Denied => matches the logic
- Approved/Disapproved => disapproval could be considered more of a personal opinion.
- Approved/Unapproved => unapproved could mean as mentioned in the comments (i.e. no decision yet given) or alternatively the (approved) decision is taken back.

Also fine is approved/rejected, although "rejected" may have a slight connotation depending on the context. It could perceived more strongly by the submitting party.